# How to set optional get in php

Tags: php

In a php file named *show.php* I used GET method to receive datas.

In newer version of my app, I have another GET method for offset. And that's an optional data.

How can I optimise php file for working with and without get methods. In another meaning, How to set optional GET method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a default value and a ternary condition?:

```
$limit = isset($_GET['limit']) ? $_GET['limit'] : 1;
$offset = isset($_GET['offset']) ? $_GET['offset'] : 1;
```

Comment: ***.com/show.php set limit and offset 1? Without any problems?

Comment: if limit or offset are not found in the get parameters, they will be 1.

Comment: It should be solved.